# Multiplying a "leading space" in autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

Consider this,

[image]

the light blue strip is width (say) 10.

The red block is linked to the light blue strip with ***leading measure***.

Say the constant on that constraint is zero. Of course, the x position of the red block will be "10" - touching the light blue strip.

Say the constant on that constraint is 13. Of course, the x position of the red block will be 10+13 == 23.

Now set the constant to zero, so x for the red block is 10 - touching the light blue strip.

Now - say you set the ***multiplier*** on the constant to, example, 1.7.  (Again the constant is default zero.)

Testing seems to show that what it "multiplies" is the ***width of*** the light blue strip.

So with 1.7 multiplier, you get 17 in the example.  1.5 multiplier, you get 15 in the example.

[image]

This is actually really handy in fact! But,

1. does anyone know if this is actually correctly the case?
2. is it really just bizarre, perhaps buggy, erratic or undocumented behaviour?
3. is it documented anywhere?

Comment: If the constant is `1`, does it still multiply the width of the blue strip, or does it multiply the constant (i.e. `1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't the "width of the light blue strip" that is being multiplied by your multiplier. It is *the `x` position as a whole*.

It happens that in your example those are the same, because your light blue strip's left edge is at zero. But move your light blue strip to the right and watch what happens! Example:

[image]

In that screen shot, the turquoise strip is 10 wide, and it is 70 from the left. Hence if the Multiplier were 0, the red square would have its `x` at 80. But the Multiplier is 2, so the red square has its `x` at 160.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's correct, although maybe not intuitive...

According to Apple's docs:

```
leading = multiplier * relationship + constant
```

so:

```
Leading Space to: measure
Constant: 0
Multiplier: 1
```

evaluates to:

```
red.leading = 1.0 * measure.trailing + 0   // == 10
```

or:

```
red.leading = 1.0 * 10 + 0    // == 10
```

If you use:

```
Leading Space to: measure
Constant: 0
Multiplier: 1.5
```

you get:

```
red.leading = 1.5 * measure.trailing + 0  // == 15
```

or:

```
red.leading = 1.5 * 10 + 0    // == 15
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html